# JSP not printing the object correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat9

I started learning Spring MVC and created a controller, added a dummy object in ModelAndView:

```
 modelAndView.addObject("pageContext", pageContext);
```

Tried to access it in JSP like this:

```
<div>${pageContext}</div>
```

But, it's printing an output like:

```
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl@3085ff7b
```

Shouldn't it print the exact object output? Using tomcat 9 and jdk8.

Could anyone please point out what might be missing?

Comment: That’s the default `toString`. I’m not sure what you’re expecting to see here. Have you looked at the `PageContext` docs? Why would you want to view it on the front end anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pageContext is the name of an implicit JSP object. Try naming something else the object you insert in the model.

modelAndView.addObject("someObject", theObject );

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I just tried with another key, it's now not printing anything, it's building an empty div. Anything else has to be configured? The Object does contain values

Comment: You’ll have to give more context, show the whole controller method.

Comment: Had some misconfiguration in the build file for jasper, the object was just Obj.builder().someVal(10).build(). Thanks.